# Finding the value of k in the following limit

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Let $f :\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with period $1$ and
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\sin^2(\pi x)f(nx)dx= \frac{1}{k}\int_0^1f(x)dx.$$
>   Find $k$.

My approach till now:

Applying half angle formula $2\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos(2x)$ I got :
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(nx)dx-
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\cos(2\pi x)f(nx)dx.$$

I can't think of a way forward from here without applying integration by parts but i don't know if its right to apply it as we don't know about the differentiability of the function $f$.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3527941/72031

Comment: Thank you. I learned something really beautiful today from it.

Comment: Learning on MSE is more enjoyable than doing the same with books. I hope you have a great time here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Exactly Sir . Sir when can we interchange summation and integral ? In what cases is it permissible ? All possible permutations like summation-integral interchange, limit-integral interchange, derivative-integral interchange. Can you please tell me about that ? I really want to know that.

Comment: Well interchange of two limit operations (remember both derivative and integral are deep down limits) is not allowed in general. Finding when this is allowed is one of the central themes in analysis. The definitive result regarding interchange of limits and integral was given by Lebesgue. Search Lebesgue DCT.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please suggest me a book to start with analysis ?

Comment: You can first try Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* then follow it with Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 g(x)f(nx)dx&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n g\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)f(t)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 g\left(\frac{t+k}{n}\right)f(t)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(t_k)\int_0^1 f(t)dt
\end{aligned}
where we used the $1$-periodicity of $f$ and the fact that by the Mean Value Theorem $\exists t_k\in [k,k+1]$ such that
$$\int_0^1 g\left(\frac{t+k}{n}\right)f(t)dt=g(t_k)\int_0^1 f(t)dt.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 g(x)f(nx)dt=\int_0^1g(t)dt\cdot \int_0^1f(t)dt.$$
Hence, from your work, it follows that as $n\to\infty$,
$$\int_0^1\sin^2(\pi x)f(nx)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(nx)dx-
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\cos(2\pi x)f(nx)dx\to \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(x)dx$$
which means that $k=2$.

Comment: woahhhh that was brilliant ! Thank you.

Comment: when can we interchange summation and integral ? Like how did you know that you can do that here? In what cases it is permitted to do so ?

Comment: The interchange is made when $n$ is fixed (and finite). So all you need is linearity.

Comment: linearity of what exactly ? The series ? pardon me I am a total novice.

Comment: Linearity of the integral. A edited my answer with a few more details.