# $f$ is 1-periodic prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \sin^2(πx)f(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, riemann-sum

I came across this very nice Question so thought of sharing it!

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function $f:R \to R$ with period $1$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \sin^2(\pi x)f(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Added the solution as an answer.

Comment: For a more general version see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3527941/72031).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution: Let $I = \int_0^1 f(t) \, dt$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)f(nx)\,dx = I \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x) \, dx + \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)(f(nx)-I)\,dx \\
= \frac 12 I + \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)(f(nx)-I)\,dx \, .
$$
Define $G(x) = \int_0^x (f(t) - I) \, dt$. Then $G'(x) = f(x) - I$ and $G(0) = G(1) = 0$. In particular, $G$ is continuous and $1$-periodic and therefore *bounded* on $\Bbb R$. Now do integration by parts:
$$
\int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)(f(nx)-I)\,dx = \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)G'(nx) \, dx \\
= - \frac \pi n \int_0^1 \sin(2 \pi x) G(nx) \, dx 
$$
and that converges to zero for $n \to \infty$ because the integral is bounded independently of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068640/121671) and this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) which states that if $\phi\in \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R})$, $f$ is a bounded $T$ periodic function and $a_n$ is any real numeric sequence, then

$$
\lim_n\int \phi(x)f(nx+a_n)\,dx=\Big(\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f\Big)\int \phi \tag{1}\label{one}
$$

In terms of the OP,  $T=1$, $a_n=0$,  and $\phi(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)\sin^2(\pi x)$. The rest follows by substituting $\phi$ on $\eqref{one}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \sin^2(πx)f(nx)dx$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \int_{r/n}^{r/n+1/n} \sin^2(πx)f(nx)dx $$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sin^2(πr/n) \int_{r/n}^{r/n+1/n} f(nx)dx$$
$nx=t$.

$$=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(\sin^2(πr/n))\frac{1}{n} \int_{r}^{r+1} f(t)dt$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt \int_{0}^{1} \sin^2(πx)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$

Comment: What is $x$ in the third and fourth ine?

Comment: Thanks Corrected it

Comment: Why are the second and third expression equal?

Comment: As n is very large, the interval of the integration is very small, so we may approximate x to be a constant in this interval, and so we can treat sin²(πx) as a constant here, and it may be taken out of the integral

Comment: Then the expressions are *approximately* equal, but not necessarily equal. – I am not saying that your end result is wrong, but you need to justify it better.

Comment: But in an infidecimal interval wouldn't they be pretty much equal? I haven't learnt the epsilon delta method yet so not sure how to be more rigorous without it 

Comment: @zhw But this step concerns only with the size of any one interval and not the number of intervals isn't?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my previous comment. You said the intervals are small, and I reminded you that the number of intervals is large. We have a sum of a large number of small numbers, so the the result is ...? It could be anything. For example $1/\sqrt n$ is small if $n$ is large, but a sum of $n$ of terms each equal to $1/\sqrt n$ is $n\cdot 1/\sqrt n = \sqrt n,$ which is large. What you need is an estimate on $|\sin(\pi x/n)-\sin(\pi k/n)|$ for $x\in [k-1,k].$

Comment: Your approach can be salvaged: Using the mean-value theorem for integrals you can show that $\int_{r/n}^{r/n+1/n} \sin^2(πx)f(nx)dx = \sin^2(π x_{n,j}) \int_{r/n}^{r/n+1/n} f(nx)dx$ for *some* $x_{n,j} $ in the interval $[r/j, (r+1)/j]$. That gives you Riemann sums converging to $\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(πx)dx$.