# Why $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)g(nt)\ dt$ goes to $\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a trigonometric polynomial with degree $N > 0$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$. I'd like to show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)g(nt)\ dt = \hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0).$$

I have learned that,
$$f(x) = \sum_{m = -N}^N\hat{f}(m)e^{imx}$$
and if $g_n(t):= g(nt)$, then
\begin{equation}\hat{g}_n(m) = \begin{cases}
\hat{g}(m/n),\ \ \ \text{if $n$ divides $m$}\\
0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}\end{equation}
So, we have then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)g(nt)\ dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{m = -N}^N\hat{f}(m)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(nt)e^{imt}\ dt.
\end{align*}
I thought I should be able to use $\hat{g}_n(m)$ but I don't have $e^{-imt}$. Is there a trick that I haven't use? Putting $e^{-imt}e^{imt}$ inside the integral doesn't seem to help as well.

Comment: Day 1, Problem 5 is a bit similar: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1994/prob_sol.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(nx)\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909180/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-int-pi-pifxgnx-dx-frac12-pi-int)